# Styling `tt` with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working with a machine-generated HTML file that contains many `tt` tags. I tried in several ways to style them, but no method has worked for me up to now: for instance,

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .a {color:red;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><tt class="a">this should be red</tt></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

is not rendered in red (at least in FF 6.0.1/Ubuntu).

Am I doing something wrong, or styling `tt` tags is not supported?

Comment: Works for me in FF 6.0.2 Windows

Comment: Works for me.  Chrome on Ubuntu 11.x

Comment: also works for me FF 6.0.2 Windows 7

Comment: Works for me with FF 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Can you reproduce it not working using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Duh. I need to double-check my firefox configuration and add-ons then. Thanks for checking anyway. I don't know what's the proper protocol in this case --- which answer should I accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kw6d5/

Works Chrome 13, Firefox 6, IE9 on Win7.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it doesn't work on certain browsers because the **tt** element is officially deprecated (see http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/tt). The recommended alternative to the **tt** tag is to use `font-family: monospace` in the CSS instead.

Comment: You'll need `white-space: pre;` as well if you want newlines observed. Bit late, but better late than never! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it in both chrome and IE and it worked great.  Try another browser and see, maybe it's firefox specific.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested, and `.a{color:red;}` appeared to style a `<tt>` with a class of `a` in FF 6 just fine (on a mac).

Possibly you have a style set on `tt` already? Try using `tt.a{ color:red; }` instead?